# Way to run code when a preference checkbox is changed?

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

I have searched everywhere and can't find anything about this:

I have a checkbox set up in a preference screen. I want to make a dialog pop up when the checkbox is checked, but i can't find a method that is called when that checkbox is checked.

I am using the eclipse IDE.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
checkboxbutton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked){

        if (isChecked){   
            CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check1);
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            cb1.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("MY_NAME",true));
            String s1="OK"; 
            AlertDialog.Builder ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(IPCamera.this);
            ad.setMessage("CHECKBOX SET");
            ad.setPositiveButton(s1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                }
            });
            ad.show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, thats very muddled. Should i put this in the preference activity or my main activity? Also, what should i put for the R.id.check1? I have an id for my checkbox, but it isn't being recognised.

Comment: If your id isnt recognised then you should clean your project first. The R.java file will create a new instance of all resources, and then...bang..it will accept your id. Replace check1 with your id. Sorry for the muddle :) replied in a hurry. Put this in the preference activity

Comment: Right, all works except that this line is giving an error: `checkboxbutton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()`, the error being that checkboxbutton cannot be resolved, and that OnCheckChangedListener cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: checkboxbutton here refers to the object of CheckBox class....see what you have written in your class and replace it with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `setOnCheckedChangeListener` and override the `CompoundButton.onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)` method to show your dialog